# Getting error when Installing map_view 0.0.10 plugin in flutter application

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement [map_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view) plugin in my flutter application. Followed the instructions provided in the plugin documentation but failed to install the plugin.

I have added the dependency for `map_view` plugin to `pubspec.yaml` as below,

```
dependencies:
map_view: "^0.0.10"
```

but after running `flutter packages get`, I am getting this error

```
Package uri has no versions that match >=0.11.1 <0.12.0 derived from:
- map_view 0.0.10 depends on version ^0.11.1
pub get failed (1)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete this from the pubspec.yaml and it works:

```
dev_dependencies:
    flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
```

The plugin developer answers the question [here.](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/13#issuecomment-356180112)